# Misaligned left and right y axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to produce two sinusoidal curves onto the same graph. the two have different amplitudes, so i have a left and right y axes. however, when i have a phase difference of Pi/4, the zero points of the two y axes are not aligned, instead being skewed differently. is there any way i can prevent this? thank you.

code:

```
function[] = improvised (a,b,c,d);
% a is time period, b is amplitude red, c amplitude blue
% d is phase shift blue relative to red
x = (0.0:0.001*a:2*a);
y = b*sin (2*pi*x/a);
z = c*sin ((2*pi*x/a)+(2*pi*d/a));
plot (x,y,'r-');
ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
yyaxis left
xlabel ('blabla')
ylabel('blabla')

yyaxis right
plot (x,z,'b-');
ylabel('blabla')
```

[on the right, the x axis crosses between 0.1 and 0, for seemingly no reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7mP3.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce. [This](https://imgur.com/jEgOtC4) is what I get for `a = .009; b = 6; c = 4; d = pi/4;` on Matlab R2017b. Please edit your answer with your inputs and your Matlab version

Comment: for what it's worth, my inputs were a = .009, b = 6, c = 0.275, d = 0.001125 (ie, a/8). thanks for the assistance, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular example that you have given, we can determine the amplitudes of the two curves programmatically. So it is possible to choose the y-axis limits of the two curves individually using the `ylim()` function as follows:

```
function[] = improvised (a,b,c,d)
% a is time period, b is amplitude red, c amplitude blue
% d is phase shift blue relative to red
x = (0.0:0.001*a:2*a);
y = b*sin (2*pi*x/a);
z = c*sin ((2*pi*x/a)+(2*pi*d/a));
plot (x,y,'r-');
ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
yyaxis left
xlabel ('blabla')
ylabel('blabla')
ylim([-b,b])

yyaxis right
plot (x,z,'b-');
ylabel('blabla')
ylim([-c,c])
```

Now when we call the function with the given parameters:

```
>> improvised(.009, 6, 0.275, 0.001125 )
```

we get the following plot.
[image]